# Convert DateTime to a specific format

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

What is the best and fastest way to convert a DateTime to this format?

> 2015-03-26T18:02:58.145798Z

Currently I receive a date from a server and I'm able to parse it and convert the date in to DateTime and the ToString() output is something like this:

> 26/03/2015 18:02:58

For converting the date I'm using this line of code:

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-03-26T18:02:58.145798Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

What is the best way to convert parsedDate back to the original format?

**EDIT: I want to convert the DateTime to this format 2015-03-26T18:02:58.145798Z as string**

Comment: What is it that you want? Do you want to convert it back to String?

Comment: the ToString("O") almost do the job, but the problem is that is missing the Z at the end of the string, any idea?

Comment: the Z is not missing, what framework version you on?

Comment: I'm writing a universal app for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 under Windows Runtime

Comment: @frenk91 use `parsedDate.ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: don't add the "final code" in your question. If you feel that the answers does not explain it enough, add your own answer with the final code. Separate the question from the answer.

Comment: I rolled back your revision, since the code you added is already explained in the added answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `DateTime` object you can convert it to a string with that particular format by using `O` as format specifier:

```
parsedDate.ToString("O")
```

or

```
parsedDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O") // if parsedDate is not UTC
```

returns `"2015-03-26T18:02:58.1457980Z"`.

---

If the `DateTimeKind` of your `DateTime` object is not `Utc` then you won't get the `Z` extension at the end of the string according to ISO8601. In the example you provided the `Z` is present because `DateTime.Parse` will recognize it and return a `DateTime` in `Utc`. Should the `Z` be missing in the original string you parse you can still assume it's UTC by using `ToUniversalTime()` on the date time object.

Comment: the uotput using ToString("O") is this  2015-04-23T08:03:39.0000000 it miss the Z at the end

Comment: @Default @frenk91 Because you use `DateTime.Now` which has `DateTimeKind.Local`. The parsed `DateTime` in the example has `DateTimeKind.Utc` in which case there will be a `Z` at the end.

Comment: @Dirk you need to correct parsedDate.UtcNow, it will not work. Add DateTime.UtcNow as an alternative and explain why the Z is only on the end for UTC

Comment: @Jaycee there is no `parsedDate.UtcNow`, If he parses the string the way he says he will get a UTC time.

Comment: @Dirk what I am saying is you are using the original DateTime variable and calling UtcNow on it, it is a static property!

Comment: @Default fixed it now. I checked for existance of the method but did not notice that is was static. My bad!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is almost what @Dirk said:

`parsedDate.ToString("O")` is the line, **but** you have to convert the DateTime to UTC: that's how you get the "Z" at the end.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more info.

**Edit:**

To convert a DateTime to UTC, use the `ToUniversalTime()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The FASTEST way, known to me, is this:

```
        ///<summary>Format the date time value as a parsable ISO format: "2008-01-11T16:07:12Z".</summary>
    public static string ISO( this DateTime dt ) {
        var ca = new char[] {
            (char) ( dt.Year / 1000 % 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Year / 100 % 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Year / 10 % 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Year % 10 + '0' ),
            '-',
            (char) ( dt.Month / 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Month % 10 + '0' ),
            '-',
            (char) ( dt.Day / 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Day % 10 + '0' ),
            'T',
            (char) ( dt.Hour / 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Hour % 10 + '0' ),
            ':',
            (char) ( dt.Minute / 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Minute % 10 + '0' ),
            ':',
            (char) ( dt.Second / 10 + '0' ),
            (char) ( dt.Second % 10 + '0' ),
            'Z',
        };
        return new string( ca );
    }
```